# Svelte/Sapper: Body empty on POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, svelte, sapper

I'm trying to create a login form using sapper, but am encountering the following problem when trying to test a basic POST fetch.

In `routes/login/login.svelte`, I have the following code which is called on a button click:

```
<script>
  let data = {"email":"test"};

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/login/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: data
    });
  };
</script>
```

Which should send what is in `data` to `routes/login/login.js` which has the following code:

```
export async function post(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  var data = req.body;
  return res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

My problem is that this only returns `{}` rather than the data sent in the svelte page. Any ideas as to why this is happening and where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When sending the data, you should also stringify it there

```js
   body: JSON.stringify(data)
```

as an extra make sure you have [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) installed and added as middleware in the server, this package will help you handle requests that have send json data in their body.

```
polka() // You can also use Express
    .use(
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        bodyparser(),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added the `JSON.stringify` bit and imported `json` from bodyparser but am still receiving a blank return for some reason

Comment: Not `bodyparser()` but `bodyParser.json()`

Comment: The `response` object in your code will not contain the actual json data returned, for that you have to do `response.json()` which returns a promise.  You can do `fetch(...).then(res => res.json())` to get the json data directly in response. (This assumes no errors were returned from the server though)

Answer (score 3):

Building on the previous answer, I'm writing here the full working solution. Your problems may be due to:

1. Not using the `json` parse middleware
2. Not treating `fetch` as a promise

Here's how I'd fix it:

1. `npm i body-parser`
2. Add the `json` middleware in your `server.js`

```js
const { json } = require('body-parser');

polka()
    .use(
      compression({ threshold: 0 }),
      json(),
      sirv('static', { dev }),
      sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });
```

3. Treat the `fetch` response as a Promise. This is how your Svelte component should look like (notice the chained `then`):

```
<script>
  let data = {"email":"test"};

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    await fetch(`your-endpoint`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res)); // {email: "test"}

  };
</script>
```